# Displaying modelState errorlist from a Web Api service in my view? (MVC 4)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using data annotation to validate any model that I plan to add and returning validation messages back to my view if rules are broken, here's the method:

```
 // POST api/Issues
        public HttpResponseMessage PostIssues(Issues issues)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.Issues.Add(issues);
                //db.SaveChanges();
                bool isValid = _unitOfWork.IssuesRepository.Insert(issues);

                if (!isValid)
                {
                    RetrieveModelStateErrors("Insert Issues", _unitOfWork.IssuesRepository.ValidationDictionary);
                    Dictionary<string, string> _errorMessages = _unitOfWork.IssuesRepository.ErrorMessages;

                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, StaticUtility.ConvertModelState_ToJDictionary(ModelState));
                }
                else
                {
                    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, issues);
                    //response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = issues.IssueID }));
                }

                return response;

            }
            else
            {
                return response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, StaticUtility.ConvertModelState_ToJDictionary(ModelState));
            }
        }
```

**Here's how I handle the errors returned, my issue jqXHR seems to be empty??? I display my list of modelState messages??:**

....

```
 success: function (result) {
                        alert("Saved");
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        extractErrors(jqXHR, validator);
                    }
```

.....

```
function extractErrors(jqXhr, validator) {

  var data = JSON.parse(jqXhr.responseText), errors = {};

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // add each error to the errors object
            alert("inside here!!");
            var errormessage = data[i].value;
            errors[data[i].key] = errormessage;
        }

        validator.showErrors(errors); // show the errors using the validator object
    }
```

Here is the ConvertModelState_ToJDictionary:

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string> ConvertModelState_ToJDictionary(ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
        {
            int x = 0;
            Dictionary<string, string> ErrorMessagesList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var modelState in modelStateDictionary.Values)
            {
                string key1 = modelStateDictionary.Keys.ToList()[x];
                foreach (var error in modelState.Errors)
                {
                    ErrorMessagesList.Add(key1, error.ErrorMessage);
                }
                x++;
            }
            return ErrorMessagesList;
        }
```

Validation rules here:

```
 public partial class Issues : IValidatableObject
    {
        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validattionContext)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SEID) )
                yield return new ValidationResult("SEID Cannot be empty", new[] { "SEID" });
            //if (IssueID == 0)
            //    yield return new ValidationResult("IssueID Cannot be 0", new[] { "IssueID" });
        }

    }
```

My model:

```
public partial class Issues
    {
        public int IssueID { get; set; }
        public string LinkingField { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateAdded { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> IRSRcvdDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FrivRcvdDate { get; set; }
        public string SEID { get; set; }
        public string ProgramCode { get; set; }
        public string TxPd { get; set; }
        public string ActionCode { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActionDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CloseDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ArgCode { get; set; }
        public string Promoter { get; set; }
        public string Preparer { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> RevenueProtected { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Cnt { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Select { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FollowUpDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> ErrRefund { get; set; }
        public string SCCode { get; set; }
        public string RcvingTeam { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> AssignDate { get; set; }
        public string RefEIN { get; set; }
        public string XTIN { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StatuteDate { get; set; }
        public string CISNum { get; set; }
        public string FormFiled { get; set; }
        public string ThirdParty { get; set; }
        public string Charact { get; set; }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
        public string Notary { get; set; }
        public string LetName { get; set; }
        public string EFIN { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> L3176G_Date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Single { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Joint { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> CleanUpNeed { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> CleanUpDone { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Paperless { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is your `result` empty? Are you using Razor?

Comment: its going to the error function? Are saying, I should rewrite as

Comment: error: function (result){...

Comment: using Jquery, its an ajax call...no need for razor

Comment: Well, modelstate errors and error handling in an `ajax` call are not the same thing. Modelstate errors are handled in the `success` callback... that's why i asked about Razor...

Comment: it never goes to the success block..I thought when you return a HttpStatusCode.BadRequest...it will head to the error block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few things:

1) Is your `ajax` call expecting a `json` response? (eg `dataType : "JSON",`) and is it getting `json` as a response? This could be a reason why your response object is empty. You can use the developer console in Chrome or one of the other browser utilities to make sure your actually getting `json`.

2) It's not possible to determine from your example what the structure of your response object is `StaticUtility.ConvertModelState_ToJDictionary(ModelState)` so its difficult to help you with accessing it. Generally, you probably want to handle `400` HTTP errors differently than `500` errors, and also `400` errors based on modelstate differently than other `400` errors.

For example:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error){
   switch(xhr.status){
      case 400:
         // parse modelstate errors:
         parseMSErrors(xhr, validator);
         // or do something else
         break;
   }
}
```

3) I suspect your web API might not be returning a JSON object. Unless you have some form of filter setup, please try the following:
 - Add a reference to [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) or some other JSON serializer
 - Try the following API response:

```
string jsonResp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StaticUtility.ConvertModelState_ToJDictionary(ModelState));

return response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, jsonResp);
```

If you're specifying JSON in your ajax, hitting your API successfully, and returning JSON (as specified) then you should be able to access the reponse object in the ajax error block.

Comment: I am still new with web api, still trying to figure it out. ADDED More details

Comment: When I run it thru, chrome I see "400: bad request" during the POST, no JSON object returned

Comment: How do I get the dictionary of errors as Json object to iterate from my ajax call?

Comment: Are you specifying `dataType: "JSON"` in you ajax call?

Comment: Yeah, it didn't help?

Comment: It doesn't look like your web API method is returning JSON. And, that would explain why your not seeing a response object.